# A way to use dynamic variable names?

Tags: lua

In Lua, is there a way to use dynamic variable names such as having the name of a variable contained in a variable?

Say I want a variable to be named "myvar2", but don't want to hard code it as in:

```
myvar2 = 55
```

But instead have another variable such as "varname" contain the name "myvar2"?

Example:

```
varname = "myvar2"

*varname = 25

print(myvar2)  --->  25
```

Comment: Why do you want or need this?

Answer (score 5):

One method is to look-up variables by name in the global environment, the table `_G`:

```
 varname = "myvar2"
 _G[varname] = 25
 print(myvar2) ---> 25
```

Note that this will not find local variables.
Useful reading: 
[PIL 14.1 – Accessing Global Variables with Dynamic Names](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html)

Comment: This answer applies to fields in any table, not just _G.

Comment: The key point here is `_G` is the environment. A table that is not the environment would need `print( mytablename.myvar2 )`. Using a table that isnt the environment is a better way if it fits the purpose. This is hackish for me.

Comment: Reading the question again, it could be that the asker is open to design recommendations. If only @lhf's question would be answered....